# In Non-ARC calls to undeclared methods with first parameter as double results in data corruption.

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Non-ARC calls to undeclared methods with the first parameter as float results in bad behavior.

Try this out. Create a class with method :

```
- (bool) methodWithDouble:(double)value andArray:(NSArray*)ary
{
    if (!ary)
        NSLog (@"Array is nil");
    return true;
}
```

Now call the method. Pass in nil for the array.

```
SomeClass *objSomeClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[objSomeClass methodWithDouble:21 andArray:nil];
[objSomeClass release];
```

You will notice that "ary" inside the method becomes non-nil.  If might even crash if the memory pointer belongs to some other object.

Now replace "double" with "int". This will work fine. Anyone knows why ... ?

Comment: What's the hardware you're running this on? ARM or the simulator on x86? 64-bit?

Comment: Simulator on 64-bit Mac, iOS 7.1 SDK

Comment: Are you seeing any compiler warnings? If not, do you have them switched off? Both of the answers below are credible and should have given you a warning.

Comment: Yes, I see the warnings. I encountered this while testing my Unit Tests which are calling methods not exposed on the SDK interface.

Comment: If you see warnings fix them!

Comment: Well @Zaph, how do you propose you run a semi-black box testing to poke into the internals of an SDK while not changing any interface ? Ignoring warnings in UnitTest is not breaking my code, so what is wrong with that ?

Comment: This post from Matt is related to how the compilers decide on types. It is a continuation on the same topic of types. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess method

```
- (bool) methodWithDouble:(double)value andArray:(NSArray*)ary
```

is not visible at compile time from place where you call

```
[objSomeClass methodWithDouble:21 andArray:nil];
```

so compiler guess the first parameter is int and not makes implicit cast of int (21) to double. If on your architecture 'sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)' the second parameter(nil) will be placed not in that position which is expected by "methodWithDouble:andArray:". Try to change this line to

```
[objSomeClass methodWithDouble:(double)21 andArray:nil];
```

or

```
[objSomeClass methodWithDouble:21. andArray:nil];
```

UPDATE:

Some clarifications.

Parameters of methods are pushed via stack. Lets assume

```
sizeof(int) == 4 
sizeof(double) == 8 
sizeof(void*) == 4 //pointers
```

so if compiler calls some method with parameters (int, void*) it pushes to stack 4 bytes for int and 4 bytes for pointer. If method expects (double, void*) it reads from stack 8 bytes for  double (and receives wrong value) and then 4 bytes for pointer (and receives some rubbish because only 8 bytes where pushed).

Comment: But what about the NSArray not being passed in as nil ? Instead it comes in with a memory pointer. When I pass in 21.0 the NSArray is filled in with nil. (Upvote for int/double answer)

Comment: It is passed as nil but it is not read correctly. Wait a minute I will update the answer.

Comment: Parameters of methods can be passed via registers. and even `double` and `long long` have same size, it may still get you wrong result

Answer (score 3):

without see the method declaration, the compiler can only guess the method signature from the arguments, and you have passed `21` to it, which is `int`, so compiler guess it is calling

```
- (bool) methodWithDouble:(int)value andArray:(NSArray*)ary
```

which is totally wrong, the calling conversion for pass `int` and pass `double` are almost always different. caller may push 4 bytes to stack and callee is expecting 8 bytes from stack and messed everything up

if your change `21` to `21.0` (double), it should work